# How to check App released in Huawei AppGallery available only for HMS devices not for GMS+HMS devices

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery-connect

I have released a application Huawei AppGallery for HMS devices. How can I test and confirm that it is released only for HMS devices.

Answer (score 0):

Please try searching the application in AppGallery of the HMS device and GMS device.

If the application is whitelisted for HMS device alone, then it is be visible in AppGallery and Install button will be enabled. In case of GMS device it wont be. [same will be applicable for GMS+HMS device, if whitelisted it will show].